# A team has won $12$ out of their $25$ games. What is the probability that they win their $26$th game?

Tags: probability

A team has won $12$ out of their $25$ games. What is the probability that they win their $26$th game?

I am having trouble solving this problem. Any help?

Comment: A hint as to the origin of the question?

Comment: There really isn't enough information given.  12/25 is not necessarily an indication of the quality of the team.  They may be one of the stronger teams in the league, but they had a slow start.  Anyway, it is sufficiently close to 50% that ti would be safer to assume that they are an average team, and their likelihood of winning is 50%, then to assume that they are slightly below average, and their record is a perfect reflection of their skill.

Comment: Doug - perfect. That's pretty much what I was thinking

Comment: Laplace would say the anser is 13/27.  See Laplace's Rule of Succession: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession

Comment: What are the stats for their opponents?

Answer (score 1):

$12/25$ is the best guess with the data available.

Comment: Is math allowed to offer best guesses? On a test, I'd rather explain why we have insufficient information to answer than to make some assumption and guess.

Comment: A best guess can sometimes be called a *maximum likelihood estimator*. Sounds better already.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Statistician do it all the time... they would call it "an unbiased estimate."

Comment: @DougM : "Unbiased estimate" is a precisely defined term. So is "maximum-likelihood estimate".  (And maximum-likelihood estimators are usually biased.) $\qquad$

Comment: @AndréNicolas : $\qquad\uparrow\qquad$

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer : You'd be surprised.  https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22point+estimation%22 $\qquad$

Comment: "Best guess" is a bit ...grumpy.  we aren't guessing anything about the team, but we are guessing the books intent.  The question makes assumptions so *we* make the assumption that the book is assuming the games played and won represent pure probabilistic outcomes.  It's not so much a "guess" as an interpretation. But maybe you are supposed to use Laplace rule of succession.

Comment: Actually, I would argue the best bet is actually 13/27 by Laplace succession.  This time it is safe to call it a guess as we are acknowledging that we are and must be making assumptions.

Comment: I am open to anything on this issue. At SE, my first inclination is to ask "is there any more information?" In this case, if the question is complete, context still matters. The answer is still expected to reflect the level of the course, if this was a school question. Similar to when I see a triangle problem, but it's geometry, early on, and no 'trig' is allowed, yet.